# Cardinality restrictions: Too many to be included in a set

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

While reading literature sometimes I stumble on such passages as

- In the first-order case, we cannot require M to contain a distinct world for each model of the first-order non-modal language, for there are too many models to form a set.
- Since there are too many ordinals to form a set, there are too many propositions to form a set.
- By hypothesis, such a sentence can contain too many variables to form a set.

What does it mean "too many to form a set"? What justifies such cardinality restrictions?

Comment: Are you familiar with Russell's paradox or the Burali-Forti paradox?

Comment: To some extent, but I don't get how it is related to large cardinality. Say, we have a restriction to form sets of some particular type (like, normal sets as in Russell's paradox), but why does it also restricts forming very large sets?

Comment: Incidentally, I think this question is not a duplicate of e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109874/do-there-exist-proper-classes-that-arent-too-big?noredirect=1&lq=1) since it doesn't presuppose $\mathsf{ZFC}$ as the framework (and indeed I think this winds up being the key point).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Tl;dr: it's not "a priori," but rather a feature of the particular choice of set theory we make.

---

As you know, there are various paradoxes in "naive" set theory which basically tell us that in any **consistent** theory of sets, certain collections can't actually be sets. The two most important examples are probably the following:

- Russell's paradox rules out the sethood of the collection of all sets not containing themselves.
- The Burali-Forti paradox rules out the sethood of the collection of all ordinals (under any appropriate definition of "ordinal").

Rigorous set theory begins with the task of whipping up an axiomatic framework (or more than one!) which avoids these paradoxes. However, **different theories may avoid paradox in different ways**. For example, in [positive set theories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#PosiSetTheo) the collection of sets which *do* contain themselves *is* a set! It's not at all clear that this set is "bigger" in any sense than the Russell collection. **The identification of size as the key criterion for sethood is a feature of some, but not all, set theories**.

---

... But in particular, it is a feature of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, which is the generally-accepted *default* set theory, and its many relatives. There, the relevant fact is the following:

> For any set $x$, there is some set $y$ such that there is no surjection from $x$ to $y$.

(In fact, we can take $y$ to be an ordinal!) This means that we can show that a given class $C$ is not a set by showing that it is "too big" in the sense that we *can* surject $C$ onto any arbitrary set.

One way to prove this is via the Burali-Forti paradox: the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ let us form the set of all ordinals onto which a given set surjects, so by Burali-Forti we know that (according to such a theory) for every set $x$ there is some ordinal $y$ which $x$ does not surject onto.

How do the $\mathsf{ZFC}$-axioms let us do this? Well, given a surjection $x\rightarrow\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$ we can "pull back" to get a (pre)well-ordering of $x$ with ordertype $\alpha$. We can then (pre)well-order the (pre)well-orderings of $x$ according to length, to get a new well-ordering $w$ of a more complicated set (a particular set of sets of binary relations on $X$). This $w$ is "longer" than every ordinal. Now the above is more-or-less uncontroversial, and all the usual set theories (to my knowledge) let you do this; where $\mathsf{ZFC}$ becomes special is when it lets you go further and say that **every well-ordering is isomorphic to some ordinal** (this is one of the paradigmatic proofs by transfinite recursion), at which point we have a contradiction with Burali-Forti.

---

Indeed, more can be said *(ignoring some issues re: phrasing)*:

> If $x$ is a collection of sets and there is some set $y$ such that there is no surjection from $x$ to $y$, then $x$ is a set.

*(This actually seems to use Choice, at least as far as I'm aware; I'll think about whether we can drop Choice in the morning.)*

So in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (and its relatives), **size is the only relevant criterion for determining sethood**.

---

An interesting question at this point is whether there are any "size distinctions" to be made among the proper classes. It turns out that this is a very rich topic, and in particular the usual axioms of set theory **do not** settle the question at all. For more about this, see e.g. the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3074975/28111).

Comment: Do ZFC axioms let us form the set of all ordinals? I thought they do not...

Comment: @LevLamberov They do not. Where did I say they did? They do let us form the set of all ordinals **onto which a given set surjects**, and we can use that - together with the fact that the class of all ordinals isn't a set - to prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that there is no set which surjects onto every ordinal (which is what I did above).

Comment: Hmmm.. Wikipedia states that "Modern axioms for formal set theory such as ZF and ZFC circumvent this antinomy by not allowing the construction of sets using terms like 'all sets with the property P'". Isn't your 'set of all ordinals onto which a given set surjects' just like this? I mean, isn't being an ordinal onto which a given set surjects a property just like P in what Wikipedia states?

Comment: @LevLamberov " Isn't your 'set of all ordinals onto which a given set surjects' just like this?" No, it's not, the construction is more complicated than that (the key axioms are **Separation** and **Replacement**, which are basically the forms of "sets-from-properties" which $\mathsf{ZFC}$ *does* allow). But it's 2 in the morning where I am so I'll add more detail in a few hours.

Comment: Just nitpicking: ZFC proves that $\{x\mid x\in x\}$ is a set. It just proves that it's empty. And it is not an element of itself. You can postulate that there is exactly one Quine atom $a$, and that it is the only set which contains itself, in that case $\{x\mid x\in x\}=\{a\}=a$ so you even have that the set of all sets which contains themselves contains itself.